# Encrypt text with a .cer file using aes in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, certificate, aes

I have a .cer file with me. From other StackOverflow links I can see how aes is used but they all mention a 16 bytes key. How can I use a .cer file for the same?

EDIT:
I ran `openssl x509 -inform der -pubkey -noout -in certificate_name.cer >public_key.pem` to get the public key. How might this be used?

I have tried:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
key = open('public_key.pem', 'r').read()
mode = AES.MODE_CBC
IV = Random.OSRNG.posix.new().read(AES.block_size)
AES.new(key, mode, IV=IV)
```

But this throws a `ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long` error

Answer (score 2):

.cer files are certificate files that contain a public/private key pair and some certificate metadata. The public/private key pair are used for asymmetric cryptography.

AES is a symmetric encryption algorithm. The .cer file is only related to AES in the sense that they're both in the broad topic of cryptography, but a .cer is not something that can be directly used as a key for AES.

I think you should address what you're trying to do at a higher level, since if you're trying to encrypt something with AES using a .cer file as a key there's been some fundamental misunderstanding (and cryptography is definitely NOT the place to just mess with it until it appears to work)

Comment: thanks for looking at this @user411133. I ran `openssl x509 -inform der -pubkey -noout -in certificate_name.cer >public_key.pem` to get the public key. Can this be used ?

Comment: @Projjol No. asymmetric and symmetric are completely different. Asymmetric encryption has separate encryption and decryption keys, is very slow, the key size is generally larger than 1024-bits. and the data size it can encrypt is limited to less than the key size. Symmetric encryption has one key for encryption and decryption, is very fast, the key size is generally 128 or 256 bits. and the data size it can encrypt is unlimited. What you need to do is 1. study encryption and 2. Add a description of what you are trying to accomplish to the question.